# Notion API Filter query construction

Tags: python-3.x, notion-api, notion

I can not get this working but need to apply 2 filters in my query - the `and` (probably core filter) I can not get to work. Included picture is of the working filter in the Notion.

I am using Python and various Notion packages and straight `requests` calls too.  I have a working query, en example for "created after", the filter works and looks like this:

```
filter = {
  "filter": {
    "timestamp": "created_time",
    "created_time": {
      "after": "2023-04-01T07:04:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Again, above works, but any variation of what I think needs to happen returns the classic error (shortened):

```
notion_client.errors.APIResponseError: body failed validation. Fix one:
body.filter.and[1].title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.

...and so on...
```

The above error came via this filter:

```
filter = {
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "timestamp": "created_time",
                "created_time": {
                    "after": "2023-04-01T07:04:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "properties": "Project",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "a211ab3d-a71b-49b9-a7a4-7b6f11e48b0c"
                }
            },
            {
                "properties": "Status",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "25350d5b-a927-4036-aba7-f509b0e390d4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Other variations, such as using the name or items other than the UUID return the same error.  At least 20 different combinations tried, same result.

If the `properties` block is taken out of the `and` and straight queried the same happens.

**I suspect the query is wrong**, but I am at a loss.  My work is modeled after the example in docs:

https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query

Thanks in advance.

[image]

### 11AprEdit

Via answer here is all the code and response.

```
import requests
import json
import notion_client
from pprint import pprint

database_id = "xoxoxoxoxoxoxo"

NOTION_TOKEN = "secret_xoxoxoxoxoxoxox"

notion = notion_client.Client(auth=NOTION_TOKEN)


notion = notion_client.Client(auth=NOTION_TOKEN)

# works fine!
hold_filter = {
  "filter": {
    "timestamp": "created_time",
    "created_time": {
      "after": "2023-04-01T07:04:00"
    }
  }
}

filter = {  # error pertains to this filter
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "timestamp": "created_time",
                "created_time": {
                    "after": "2023-04-01T07:04:00"
                }
            },
            # commenting out the next 2 objects in this list also works
            {
                "property": "Project",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "a211ab3d-a71b-49b9-a7a4-7b6f11e48b0c"
                }
            },
            {
                "property": "Status",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "25350d5b-a927-4036-aba7-f509b0e390d4"
                }
            }
            # end sketchy part
        ]
    }
}


def get_all_page_from_db():
    search_database = notion.databases.query(
        database_id,
        **filter
    )
    return search_database

print(get_all_page_from_db())
```

Generates:

```
 raise APIResponseError(response, body["message"], code)
notion_client.errors.APIResponseError: body failed validation. Fix one:
body.filter.and[1].title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].status should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].created_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].created_time should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].last_edited_by should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].last_edited_time should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].formula should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].rollup should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].or should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.filter.and[1].and should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
```

I have tried variations on "id"  and "equals" from the direct object UUID to a precise copy-paste of the name.  All in accordance with the docs.

The query fragment for "created after" always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried querying my database using the part of your code that you mention as problematic. After reading through and trying example cases from [Filter Database Entries](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query-filter#compound-filter-conditions), it seems to me that one cannot use `"id"` in filter object, it has to be the property type instead. Since you have a `"rich_text"` and a `"select"` property, the code should be as follows:

```
filter = {
    "filter": {
        "and":[
            {
                "property": "Project",
                "rich_text": {
                    "contains": "!-☀️-Daily"
                }
            },
            {
                "property": "Select",
                "select": {
                    "equals": "In Progress"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured that out too. For me ID and UUID/similar are always searchable.  So bad on Notion.

I almost have this working. Had to bang it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the filter object is using a non-existing field.

I guess that if you **replace** `properties` with `property` then this should work fine. So your JSON string should be like this:

```json
{
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "timestamp": "created_time",
                "created_time": {
                    "after": "2023-04-01T07:04:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "property": "Project",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "a211ab3d-a71b-49b9-a7a4-7b6f11e48b0c"
                }
            },
            {
                "property": "Status",
                "id": {
                    "equals": "25350d5b-a927-4036-aba7-f509b0e390d4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- You can find the definition in this section of the documentation:
  [the filter object](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query-filter#the-filter-object)
- And the example: [compound filter conditions](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query-filter#compound-filter-conditions)

**PS**: Here I am assuming that your property names are exactly `Project` and `Status`

Comment: Nope. I do not think compound filtering is possible in Notion.  I will add all current code on OP. I will also include error in the edit.  Appreciate the try, but I think there is a Notion problem. Again, read ALL the docs, including what you shared, no examples of this working anywhere I can find. People drop off right before you actually get to compound (formal use of "AND").

Comment: According to the documentation it seems so, you can find examples in the second link, did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: Yes, the second link is what I used for reference and example in trying to solve for a few days prior.

Comment: and did you try to replace `properties` with `property`? because I think that is the issue. It would be nice if you can replace it and let us know if that works

Comment: I did replace, same error. I tried all possible variations of plural/not, title case, all lower, etc.  Same error.  I am going to continue to bang on this I will update if I get a solution.